N1ql - Remove specific key from multi level array
I need to remove "333" name's key from below as part an update query.
At the end, should be only "111" and "222".
"AAA": [
    "BBB": [
        "CCC": [
            {
              "name": "111"
            },
            {
              "name": "222"
            },
            {
              "name": "333"
            }
          ]
      ]
  ]

Below update worked but it is not removing the entire key, it only replacing the key by a "".
update default d
set data3.CCC[3] = null
    FOR data3 IN data4.BBB
        FOR data4 IN d.AAA WHEN data3.CCC[3].name = "333" END
WHERE ANY data4 IN  d.AAA SATISFIES (ANY data3 IN data4.BBB
 SATISFIES (ANY data2 IN data3.CCC SATISFIES data2.name = "333" END) END) END

It updated as below:
"AAA": [
    "BBB": [
        "CCC": [
            {
              "name": "111"
            },
            {
              "name": "222"
            },
            **""**
          ]
      ]
  ]

But should be as below:
"AAA": [
    "BBB": [
        "CCC": [
            {
              "name": "111"
            },
            {
              "name": "222"
            }
          ]
      ]
  ]

Please help, thanks!

The example with AAA,BBB,CCC isn't valid JSON, and I can't quite figure out exactly what it's meant to be. Can you just paste some examples docs directly? But I will say you might want to check out UNSET: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html#unset-clause
